# How to superimpose polygons over ordination plot in vegan package in R

Tags: r, vegan

I have a large dataset that has species counts at different points. I used vegan to create an ordination plot that shows my species and sites. Each site has a habitat type associated with it. I would like to plot the habitat type as polygons over the ordination plot. I'm not sure how to do this.

I've tried playing around with ordihull and ordiellipse but I get various errors.

This is how I create my NMDS:

```
df<- cast(df, Cluster + Point + Habitat ~ Species, value='ABUNDANCE', fun.aggregate = sum) 
df<- (df[c(4:63)]) 
df<- as.matrix(as.data.frame(df), drop=FALSE) 
dfNMDS <- metaMDS((df), trymax=100, k=2)
```

This gives me a nice plot:

```
ordiplot(dfNMDS ,type="n", xlim=c(-2,2))              
orditorp(dfNMDS ,display="species",col="red",air=0.01)
```

But when I try using ordihull I get completely lost. I tried to include the point ID and the habitat type for each point in the NMDS and then do this:

```
    ordihull(df,groups=Habitat,display="sites",draw="polygon",col="grey90",label=F)
```

but I get: Error in seq(along = groups) : object 'Habitat' not found.

I'm honestly shooting in the dark here and can't find any guides that show how to plot polygons based on variables in the original dataset. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I figured out how to do it if I make a character string of the habitats for each point and add that into ordihull: ordihull(COMPALLNMDS,groups=treat,draw="polygon",col="grey90",label=F). Where treat is my character string. This can't be the best way though?

Comment: All right I figured it out, it's always simpler than you think. You just have to go to the df you get from cast() and then make a character string out of the column of interest, in my case habitat: treat <- as.character(df$Habitat).

Comment: You can answer your own question if you think it may help others with a similar question

Comment: You don't need to do even that. It is sufficient that you tell where is your `Habitat`, and also you must say what you want to plot. So you should have `with(df, ordihull(dfNMDS, Habitat, ...))` or if you like dollars (I don't) `ordihull(dfNMDS, df$Habitat, ...)`. The first argument of `ordihull` must be the ordination result (`dfNMDS`), and then you need a variable that gives the groups for hulls. That variable is in `df` and you must use either `with(df, ordihull(...))` or directly showing the variable in `df` with the `$` notation (i.e., `df$Habitat`)